# How do I wrap the Add To Cart button text in woocommerce in span tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically, this is my desired output

```
<a href="#" data-quantity="1" class="button">
   <span>Add to Cart Button Text</span>
</a>
```

I can change the text with this function

```
// Change add to cart text on product archives page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_text_archives' );  

function woocommerce_add_to_cart_button_text_archives() {
   return __( '<span>Add to Cart Button Text</span>', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

But I don't want that HTML in my string. I don't know where I would put it

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone is interested, I achieved it with JS, or jQuery rather by targeting the class that woocommerce already puts on it and wrapping the inner label with the HTML, like so

```
//replace the class for whatever yours shows
$( '.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart' ).wrapInner( "<span></span>");
```